# How can I use binding for a different entity inside a Table control?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a SAPUI5 Table which has aggregation 'items' bound to the 'Expenses' entity of my OData.
'Expenses' is a part of the main Entity 'Claim', there is an Association in the OData between them. I am using the $expand command in the call to get the main ClaimSet with the expanded entity inside.
`<Table items={odata>Expenses} ...`

I have a Delete button in each row I want to hide if the main entity 'Claim' has the flag 'submitted: true'. This is now a read only entry so the button should not be shown.

The FlexibleColumnLayout page I'm using is bound to the odata ClaimSet.

```
var oView = this.getView().byId("ObjectPageLayout");
...
oView.bindElement({
    path: "/" + sObjectPath, //looks like: /ClaimSet('12345')
    model: "odata"
});
```

I cannot use `visible="{odata>Submitted}"` for the button, as 'odata>' is now referring to the Expenses entity, not the Claim entity. I am able to access Claim outside of the table, for example a the top of the view in the header section.

How can I access the main Claim entity inside the context of the Expense entity?
Is there a way of doing this without creating a separate jsonmodel? I'd like to keep it inside the XML if possible.

Comment: You try to do it via a formatter function. There you have access to what every you pass from the table, but should also be able to access the bindingcontext of your view.

Answer (score 0):

Or maybe you can loop on your dataset and add the submitted flag from Claim Set to Expense Set itself checking on some key fields!

Not sure of how the both sets look, so not sure if this will help you or not! but you can always try!!

Answer (score -1):

`visible="{odata>/submitted}"` should do the work.
With `odata>` you tell the model, and with the `/` you tell the absolute path of a property of this model and not of the aggregation.

Be careful with the capitalization. If is "submitted" put that and not "Submitted".

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. I attached a formatter to it to see the value and it was 'undefined'.

Comment: My bad, this only works if you set a new model to the view with the property.
Can you access the value of submitted in the controller? And then assign this value to a model binded to the view. For example:
var oViewModel = new JSONModel({
    submitted: true, // Here the value of your submitted
});
this.setModel(oViewModel, "objectView");

And then bind with visible="{objectView>/submitted}"

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, but I was hoping there would be a more elegant way. I think accessing the parent entity from inside the binding of a child control is a common enough use case.